# Google API Down?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am experiencing an issue where the Google CSE API returns the below error message.  It was working fine yesterday but is now returning the error message.  Also, I have tried setting it up on multiple devices, and has still returned the same error, I am wondering if anybody else if having a similar issue?

`<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=search+test%3F&cx=017576662512468239146%3Aomuauf_lfve&key=AIzaSyDAtLtCNLRicMACGZEOnJE38gQ_omhbSKE&alt=json returned "Bad Request">`

This is the line of code executing the search:

`res = service.cse().list(q=query, cx=g_cse_id, start=start).execute()`

Answer (score 0):

API is working key is the issue. Try generating a new one from the google console. I tried it with my key and same request is working.

You can get the key from here https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview